# Magento to CRM: I only want to trigger an operation from a specific customer group

Tags: php, magento, sugarcrm

We purchased a bridge between Magento and SugarCRM and it works well but I only want to push the customers and their orders from a few specific customer groups in Magento because we have different divisions. The product support team sent me the following:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == GROUP_NUMBER) return true; else return false;
```

Where `GROUP_NUMBER` is the number of the groups you need.

So I did:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == 12) return true; else return false;
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whenever I see the phrase "it doesn't work" in a bug report, I tend to inform the writer that they should ban it from their lexicon entirely `;)`. Can you explain what you expected to happen, and what actually happened? Error messages? White screen? Is this in a web context or a cron/console script? etc.

Comment: Your code see correct, did you check to see if group id 12 exist `return (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == 12) ? true : false;`

Comment: halfer thanks for your response. to clarify: when i added the condition, the contact info in the CRM wasn't updated with the recent order. no error messages, white screen etc.. this is a web context.

Comment: You might want to try, on a test setup, to determine what is being returned from this. So now nothing gets updated where before everything was?